# Cordova FCM plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm very new to cordova. I have installed this plugin from [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm) page. My question is where do I put this code if I'm not using `ionic`?:

`FCMPlugin.onTokenRefresh(function(token){
    alert( token );
});`

I have managed to the token on Chrome using official firebase documentation, but the same does not work on Firefox and cordova. 
If I put the above code in the index.html file it does work and I don't get errors whatsoever. I seen so many videos on Youtube that use `ionic` and they put this code in `.ts` file. When I started my project I did not use ionic. Do I need to use ionic for this plugin to work?

NB: my main aim is to get the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as its cordova plugin there's no need to create ionic project you can write this code in your js file on cordova platform ready function

just like jquery document ready

if have just created project and installed plugin sample JavaScript will be at www/js/ folder

Comment: Thank you very much @harsh. That helped me a lot!